# From boot Spring Batch application @BeforeStep method of the ItemWriter calling before of @BeforeStep method of the ItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm studing SpringBatch, I have a problem during the boot Spring call ItemWriter before ItemProcessor. Why?

```
public class PollingReader implements ItemReader<File> {
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) throws NotDirectoryException {..}
    @AfterStep
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {..}
}
    
public class PollingWriter implements ItemWriter<File> {
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {..}
    @AfterStep
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {..}
..
}

public class PollingProcessor implements ItemProcessor<File, File> {
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {..}
    @AfterStep
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {..}
}
```

And the method of the @AfterStep ItemProcessor is called before of the method @AfterStep ItemWriter.

**I expected this cycle call for @BeforeStep:**

- ItemReader
- ItemProcessor
- ItemWriter

but I have this result:

- ItemReader
- ItemWriter
- ItemProcessor

**and for @AfterStep I expected:**

- ItemWriter
- ItemProcessor
- ItemReader.

but I have this result:

- ItemProcessor
- ItemWriter
- ItemReader

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects are polymorphic: they are both item reader/processor/writer *and* `StepExecutionListener`s (as proxies, to be more precise). When Spring Batch runs StepExecutionListeners before/after a step, it does not see them as reader/processor/writer, and the order of their execution is not necessarily the same as they are called in a chunk-oriented step (in fact, the order is undefined in that case).